# Tinymce vue: How to render Vue component inside

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tinymce, vue-component, tinymce-5

Do you have any information how to approach the problem of rendering the vue component inside the tinymce editor ?

I am looking in something similar like here https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/tutorials/using-react-in-a-widget.html#demo

but that is for CKeditor and react.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this?